# How to retrieve the position in a ListView with Firebase results

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm **not** using `FirebaseAdapter` or any `Firebase-UI` dependency, I have made this completly native for now, but I'm getting a problem at this line trying to pass extras:

> mRootDatabase = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);
>
> Required DatabaseReference , Found UserPojo

```
public void clickListItems(ListView listView,final DatabaseReference mRootDatabase) {
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Clicked: " + getmList().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mRootDatabase = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, UserEdit.class);
                intent.putExtra("uid", mRootDatabase.getKey());
                intent.putExtra("Name",getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getName());
                intent.putExtra("Email", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getEmail());
                intent.putExtra("Pay", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getPay());
                intent.putExtra("LastCon", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getLastCon());
                intent.putExtra("FirstCon", getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position).getFirstCon());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

In `FirebaseListAdapter` you can use `getRef()` in order to do this faster, but im wondering how to approach the same without it because my app does not have implemented any FirebaseAdapters , and I dont want to redo all my code again

Edit:

This is how I got my adapter

```
 public ArrayAdapter<UserPojo> getAdapter(Context adapterContext) {
        return new ArrayAdapter<UserPojo>(adapterContext,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getmList());
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to change the following line of code:

```
mRootDatabase = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);
```

to

```
mRootDatabase = adapter.getRef(position);
```

In which `adapter` variable is the actual adapter that you are using to display the data.

**Edit:**

You cannot use `getRef()` method, unless you are using Firebase-UI library. You cannot get the `DatabaseReference` object from the `ArrayAdapter` object. None of [the methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) inside this class return a `DatabaseReference` object. The only way in which you can achieve this is to use [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) library.

Comment: hey Alex, I'm about to try it ! got off work yesterday and leaved this at work, will notice you :)

Comment: getRef is not working since I'm not using FirebaseListAdapter, let me explain more in the question, just updated how I got the adapter

Comment: @Todd Yes, I think it will. Give it a try and keep me posted.

Comment: my getAdapter returns an ArrayAdapter

Comment: just tried the adapterView but it seems it cannot apply with mRootDatabase = adapterView....

Comment: No, you didn't understand. First, there's no need to create that method that returns an ArrayAdapter. Just make the ArrayAdapter variable global, instantiate where you need in your activity and that variable `adapter` or `arrayAdapter`, wherever you name it, use it in the code above, right?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I will try it now

Comment: Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: My adapter is of the type UserPojo and i cant use getRef since I'm not using FirebaseListAdapter or any Firebase-UI based

Comment: Ok but if you are using that line of code, what does it return?

Comment: It shows an error if I try to get the position and store it into that DatabaseReference

Comment: mRootDatabase = getAdapter(mContext).getItem(position);   Found userPojo required DatabaseReference

Comment: That's correct but I cannot said in my answer to use that line of code but: `mRootDatabase = adapter.getRef(position);`, right? Try to use as I wrote it in my answer. What is happening?

Comment: if I try with getRef I need to implement a FirebaseListAdapter adapter; ... I cant use getRef without Firebase-UI

Comment: Thanks alex, firebase should allow us to get those objects to work without that dependency but I gues they will do in the future

Comment: you think there is not a workaround to solve this issue? In my searchView I have solved it getting the uid when I query the results, but in this case is a list with data, maybe we can pass the uid to each element somehow?

Comment: As I understand you need to to get the reference not the id. But using an id you can get the reference, maybe you can solve the problem. I didn't try. But remember, the `ArrayList` class and and the `FirebaseListAdapter` are two different classes that not share many thing in common. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to assign a Pojo to a Database Reference, instead you would need to assign it to the actual pojo and reference it that way
Something like this

```
UserPojo User = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Comment: This is right for get the position of the items at the list, but not for databasereference, since my getKey cant get the user who have clicked